# Select item from a list based on an array

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings, which contains information, which I want to save in separate variables. 
The .txt file contains line with this kind of information:

> 1 kitchen 1   microwave   microwave2  relevant    0.0025  1.29    0.88    1.29

```
var index = Enumerable.Range(2, 3).ToArray();
string objectInformationText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("objectList.txt");
string[] objectInformation = objectInformationText.Split('\t');
```

Now, I want to extract items from `objectInformation` based on my index (i.e. item 2 and 3). The output should be a subset only containing items 2 and 3 from the list.

Comment: Question is unclear. You do not show a list of strings but an array of chars.

Comment: Please update your post to include the expected output for your sample inputs.

Comment: Without knowing the contents of `objectList.txt` it is very hard to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution can be using lambda `Select` function as follow:

```
var result = index.Select(x => information[x]).ToList();
```

Comment: The output I get from that is: System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateSelectIterator>c__Iterator10`2[System.Int32,System.String]

Comment: @JAQuent you can add `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to get a list or array result.

Answer (score 1):

While @OmG's answer is correct, the alternative for creating a temp collection of indexes in your case would be using Skip/Take linq selectors.

```
objectInformation.Skip(2).Take(3)
```

This will obviously work only for contiguous span of indexes.

Comment: I has to be non-contiguous because I want to save every ith item in separate variable.

Answer (score 1):

In linQ there is a lot of way to select based on the index.

```
string input = "1 kitchen 1 microwave microwave2 relevant 0.0025 1.29 0.88 1.29";
var spt = input.Split(' ');

//Select everything after the 1 element:
var afterTitle = spt.Skip(1);

//Select from index 2 to 5 incuding them -> 1 microwave microwave2 relevant
var from2to5 = spt  .Skip(2)  // Skip index 0, 1
                    .Take(4); // Take 2,3,4,5

//Select based on a Index list, OmG's answer is a better alternative for this one.
int[]  idx = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
var inIdx = spt.Where((value,index)=> idx.Contains(index));
```

The last exemple will be usefull when the index needed could be calculated.

```
//Select only the Even one
var even = spt.Where((value,index)=> index%2==0);
```